# Deleting Material-UI TextField value shows old typed value ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a SearchBar in my ReactJS application. Here is the code for it:

```
import React, { useState, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

//internal
import Colors from '../globals/Colors';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textFieldLabel: {
    fontSize: 18,
    "&$focusedLabel": {
      color: Colors.firstColor,
      backgroundColor: Colors.whiteColor,
    },
  },
  focusedLabel: {}
})

function SearchBar({ label, onChange, className }, ref) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [text, setText] = useState()

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    text,
    setText
  }))

  return (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      size="small"
      className={className}
      value={text}
      InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.textFieldLabel,
          focused: classes.focusedLabel
        }
      }}
      onChange={(event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
        onChange(event.target.value)
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default forwardRef(SearchBar)
```

In another class where is used, I try at some point to **delete the typed value** inside of it. This is how I use the component:

```
<SearchBar
   ref={searchBarRef}
   label={currentUser.role === 1 ? i18n.t('dashboard.searchAdmin') : i18n.t('dashboard.search')}
   className={classes.search}
   onChange={(value) => setSearch(value)}
/>
```

And when I **delete** the values I use this code:

```
setSearch()
searchBarRef.current.setText()
```

**My problem is:**

Both `text` value from `SearchBar` component and my `search state` will become `null`, but the `TextField` will still show the typed value.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

If anyone wonders your value might still be seen:

When setting your `textfield value` your should set initial state as `empty string ''` instead of `null`